# Let $A \subset \left[a, b\right)$ be Lebesgue measurable. Show, that $F (x) = \mu (\left[a, x\right) \cap A)$ is continous on $\left[a,b\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \left[a, b\right)$ for $- \infty < a < b < \infty$ be Lebesgue measurable. Show, that $F (x) = \mu (\left[a, x\right) \cap A)$ for $a \le x \le b$ is continous on $\left[a,b\right]$

---

I honestly don't know where to start here. My idea would be to somehow argue that because $\mu$ is continuous, then $F$ must be continuous too. But this seems too easy.

Another idea I'd have is to do the following: Because we know, that $A \subset \left[a, b\right)$, this means, that

$$\left[a, x\right) \cap A = \left[a, y\right]$$ for some $a \le y \le x$. This means, that we can instead of $F(x)$ use

$$G(y) = \mu (\left[a, y\right])$$

$$G^{-1} (\mu (\left[a, y\right])) = \left[a, x\right]$$

So a closed image gives you a closed pre-image, which is one of the conditions for $G$ to be continous. And if $G$ is continuous, then $F$ is, too.

---

I kind of know that my attempt is not good, because I assume that we should do it in a completely different way.

Comment: Just because $A\subset [a,b)$ you don't generally have that $[a,x)\cap A = [a,y]$. What if $A$ was finite for example?

Comment: @Snildt True. So, I don't really know how to do this exercise then.

Comment: What do you know about $\mu$? This is false without more assumptions on the measure.

Comment: @operatorerror I literally wrote everything down, there's no more information on that. I'd guess that as we're talking about $A$ being Lebesgue measurable, then $\mu$ must be the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @operatorerror I read it as $\mu$ being the Lebesgue measure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intersection is not necessarily an interval. You can use continuity of measure though, take $h\geq 0$, then for $x\in (a,b)$
$$
|\mu(A\cap [a,x))-\mu(A\cap [a,x+h))|=\mu(A\cap[x,x+h))\leq \mu([x,x+h)\to \mu(\{x\})=0.
$$
and similarly for $h<0$.

Continuity at the endpoints follows similarly. I leave those details to you.

Comment: Why is $|\mu(A\cap [a,x))-\mu(A\cap [a,x+h))|=\mu(A\cap[x,x+h))$ ?

Comment: Let $B\subseteq A$, then $\mu(A)-\mu(B)=\mu(A\setminus B)$ since $\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(B)=\mu(A\setminus B\cup B)=\mu(A)$.

Comment: That's what I don't understand: Why is $(A\cap [a,x)) \backslash (A\cap [a,x+h)) = A \backslash [x,x+h)$ ?

Comment: @anon take the set difference the other way so that you subtract the smaller set from the bigger one.